# Return undefined in RSpec mock

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, mocking, undefined

I have written some code that makes use of Ruby's `defined?` keyword.

I would like to test this using RSpec but I cannot think of a way to make the method return something thats undefined for testing purposes.

Here is my test -

```
my_service = class_double('MyService').as_stubbed_const(transfer_nested_constants: true)
    
allow(my_service).to receive(:something).and_return(UNDEFINED_HERE)

expect(something_else).to receive(:fail!)
```

Here is my code -

```
has_result = false
attempts = 0

until has_result do

      result = MyService.something(object)

      if defined? result

        has_result = true

      else

        attempts += 1 
      end
end
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What exactly do you want to return? An error message like the one raised when you call a method on an undefined object? Or do you want to return the return value of `defined?(undefined_object)`? Perhaps it would be easier to understand when you share the code you want to test.

Comment: It is hard to tell how simulate your case without example from your side but I can suggest you to try return block. Something like `allow(my_service).to receive(:something).and_return { some_undefined_variable }`. See https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation

Comment: @gotva How to a set a variables value to undefined is what id like to know. (I know undefined isn't a value) Thanks

Comment: @spickermann Code added. Thanks!

Comment: Well looking at your code: ruby will wait for response from `MyService.something(object)` it means the response will be value or exception of `undefined ...` . If it is value - it will be defined, if it is exception - it is necessary to catch them. I suppose that you would like to wait for long request. I would use `Timeout` (https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html). `Timeout::timeout(5) { MyService.something(object) }` and catch timeout exception and do `attempts += 1 ` if it is ok - save result and `has_result = true`

Comment: This^ I'd claim your code would never land in the `else` branch, because your method would either return something (even `defined? nil` evaluates to "nil" string, and this evaluates to "true") or raise an exception.